# Runtime exception and Checked exception

Tags: java, exception

There are so many exceptions, and it is not easy to remember. Is there any rule to know which kinds of exception will fall in which type (runtime vs checked), so that we know in which case we need to catch and in which case we just throw an exception? Thanks!

Comment: ***No*** exceptions are thrown at compile-time.

Comment: The exceptions aren't thrown at compile-time, but for checked exceptions a check on the *handle-or-declare rule* is performed at compile-time.

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. What I want to know is how can we tell if an exception is checked or unchecked. Do we need to memorize it? For example, FileNotFound Exception is checked exception. Why it is not a Runtime Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, *no exceptions are compile-time exceptions*. The differentiation is *checked exceptions* vs. *unchecked exceptions*. The differentiation is made by the compiler by behaving as if each and every operation (method, constructor and initializer block) signature always implicitly includes `throws Error, RuntimeException` in its declaration. This way, the *handle-or-declare* rule, which means the compiler forces you to either handle an exception in a `catch` clause or declare an exception with a `throws` declaration is disabled for `Error` and `RuntimeException` - they are always implicitly declared.

So we overall have the following categories:

Compiler-treatment:

- unchecked exception (handling is optional): `RuntimeException` and `Error`
- checked exception (handle-or-declare rule applies): All other exceptions, including `Throwable`.

Categories:

- `Error` - we usually do not catch these.
- `RuntimeException` - catching depends on root cause.
- `Exception` - we must handle or declare them (compiler enforces).

`Error` is easy to remember. If the VM or one of its APIs thinks it's a defect of the VM or the API that causes the issue, it's an `Error`. *Usually we do not catch `Error`s*, although there are a few prominent examples, like these:

- catching `OutOfMemoryError` in resource allocating code to let the application continue after displaying an error message to the user. I.e. the user wants to load an image that's too big.
- catching `AssertionError` in Unit Test frameworks. (They actually catch `Throwable`, but `AssertionError` is treated specially, it's a test failure, not a test error.)

Runtime exceptions are exceptions which do not happen if the program was written correctly, as long as the conditions that could lead to these exceptions do not depend on the user. For example, `Integer.parseInt(String) throws NumberFormatException`. If the String that is converted is coming from the program itself, it should be correct and we wouldn't care about the exception. If the String that is converted is coming from the user, we would usually rather `catch NumberFormatException` than letting the user crash the program by means of faulty input.

Other exceptions are used where the fault condition is somewhat likely but the program is always expected to handle them in some way. For example, if you open a file, it could always be that the file doesn't exist, cannot be read due to lack of permissions or locking, or that the storage is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be new about things just catch everything... (horrible idea though only for the lazy) Otherwise look at the javados and it will tell you what is throw with each method.

```
try {
   // this code
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Yeah if you have an issue at compile it means it just doesn't compile therefore doesn't exist and cannot run.

Comment: If you want to catch _everything_ that can be thrown, use `Throwable`.

Comment: @August: Don't catch `Throwable` under penalty of public shaming.

Comment: @Makato: Public shaming is too generous.  I'd recommend defenestration.  Especially for Windows users :-)

Answer (score -1):

Do not catch RuntimeExceptions and Errors, catch other exceptions or add `throws` to method declaration

Comment: That's wrong. Example: `NumberFormatException`. It's a `RuntimeException` and if the origin of input is coming from the user I'd rather `catch` it than having bogus user input crash the program. Another example: `OutOfMemoryError`. If I read the size of an image and now am using the size to allocate the array, I'd rather catch `OutOfMemoryError` and tell my user that the VM needs more memory than simply crash the program - besides, the program might happily continue after `OutOfMemoryError` in such a situation.

Comment: @ChristianHujer - Continuing from an OOME is *unsafe* in general.  1) The OOME may have occurred at a point in which your application or some library was updating something critical.  You don't know if data structures have been damaged.  2)  If the OOME was due to a leak, then you may not be able to keep going much longer anyway.

Comment: The best thing to do is to bail out.  It is OK to catch the OOME and try to produce a helpful error message.  But you *should* then bail out!

Comment: It's true that care must be taken as to ensure that the cause of the `OutOfMemoryError` is not mistaken. It is not unsafe in this case: `try { int[] data = new int[bigNumber]; } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {...}`. It's also not unsafe if I found the cause to be in my own memory allocation by analyzing the stack trace.

Comment: @ChristianHujer - Q: How do you know if the next OOME is going to be caused by the same problem as the one that you analysed?  A: In general, you don't.  This is the same as catching NPEs.  In general, you can't be sure that the source / cause of the NPE is the one you are expecting.  I said it is unsafe **in general** ... not always.  What that means is that you should only do it in the limited subset of cases where it is provably safe.

Comment: @StephenC If I do `try { int[] data = new int[bigNumber]; }` I do not know if `bigNumber` was too big by 1 byte or more. Still, no reason to bail out always. Imagine, Unit Test frameworks, Web Containers and all that stuff would NOT catch things like OOME. It's simply wrong to say "never catch OOME" or "if you do, still bail out". Of course care must be taken, one needs to know what he's doing, but  bailing out is not mandatory, I don't want an OutOfMemoryError in a stupid Servlet crashing my Tomcat, I don't want an OutOfMemoryError in a stupid method crashing my Unit Test run.

Comment: @ChristianHujer - there is ParseException which is not RuntimeException and there is NumberFormatException which is RuntimeException

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev That's true. Do you happen to know which API method throws a checked exception for parsing a String containing a number in hexadecimal format? I did a quick check and couldn't find any, but maybe I just missed it and you happen to know? Point is, we cannot always choose whether an exception is checked or unchecked when we're the user of an API.